# Spring Integration version 3.0: Web Service request and response

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-integration, synchronous

Here my requirement, I have a web service and when there is a request comes and it goes through validation and then transformation, and at last to the request MQ Queue.

And My requirement is I will wait few second for response which I will get from response MQ Queue, I need to get the message from MQ Queue and send it in response channel. So its synchronous, if I didn't get the response in a specific interval where my current thread is waiting, I will send an error as response.

The below configurations works till I send the request, but am not able to bind the message driven channel adapter to my reponseChannel.

**This is my application context**

```
<bean id="validatingInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
    <property name="xsdSchema" ref="schema" />
    <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
    <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="loggingInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"></bean>

<bean id="myServiceDef"
    class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="schema" ref="schema" />
    <property name="portTypeName" value="myServiceGateway" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="http://localhost:8080/myapp/getData" />
</bean>

<bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="classpath:Request.xsd" />
</bean>

<bean id="myService" class="a.b.c.d.MyServiceResponder" />

<int:channel id="requestChannel" />
<int:channel id="responseChannel" />

<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="myServiceGateway"
    request-channel="requestChannel" reply-channel="responseChannel"
    error-channel="errorChannel" reply-timeout="10000" />


<int:service-activator id="myServiceActivator"
    ref="myService" input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="transformData" />

<int:channel id="transformData" />

<int-xml:xslt-transformer id="transformChannel"
    input-channel="transformData" output-channel="initiaterChannel"
    xsl-resource="classpath:my.xsl" />

<int:channel id="initiaterChannel" />
<int:channel id="outputJMS" />

<int-jms:outbound-gateway   id="jmsOutGateway"
                request-destination="destinationQueue"
                request-channel="initiaterChannel"
                reply-channel="responseChannel"
                connection-factory="jmsQueueConnectionFactoryCached"
                reply-timeout="10000"
                receive-timeout="10000"
                correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID" />

<bean id="destinationQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="${mqJavaProducerQueueName}" />
    <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
</bean>

<!-- 
  RESPONSE time 10 sec, if any message in myOutputQueueName, then response has been sent to ws client,
  else an error response sent.
  myOutputQueueName get the response from other 3rd party
--> 

<int-jms:inbound-gateway id="gate11" request-channel="outputJMS"
    request-destination-name="${myOutputQueueName}" 
    auto-startup="true"
    error-channel="errorChannel"
    reply-timeout="10000"
    request-timeout="10000"
    reply-channel="responseChannel"  connection-factory="jmsQueueConnectionFactoryCached" />

<int-xml:validating-filter discard-channel="errorChannel"
                           id="inputValidator" 
                           input-channel="outputJMS" 
                           output-channel="validatedchema"
                           schema-location="classpath:Message.xsd" 
                           schema-type="xml-schema"
                           throw-exception-on-rejection="true" />


<int:channel id="validatedchema" />

<int-xml:xslt-transformer id="transformChannel"
                          input-channel="validatedchema" 
                          output-channel="transformOutput"
                          xsl-resource="classpath:output.xsl" />

<int:channel id="transformOutput" />

<int-xml:validating-filter discard-channel="errorChannel"
                           id="outputValidator" 
                           input-channel="transformOutput"
                           output-channel="responseChannel" 
                           schema-location="classpath:Response.xsd"
                           schema-type="xml-schema" 
                           throw-exception-on-rejection="true" />
```

And My Service activator, which actually send the request to request MQ Queue and wait for the response.

```
MyReplyService.java
@ServiceActivator
    public Message<?> sendRequest(Message<?> message) {
    outputJMS.send(....);

   return responseToWSClient;
```

Whatever I return here in responseToWSClient, actually received by WS client. 
What I am missing here to have the response from transformToOutput channel in my service activator. Kindly advise.

I have edited my application context, but I am still not able to achieve what I am intend to. I think I didn't get you properly. @gary and @Artem

My WS client expect a response, and the request goes to a queue, and the response I got from some other 3rd party to a response queue[IBM MQ Q], and my ws request after sending the request wait for response in response queue, if got any messages read it and send it as response to ws client after some transformation and validations. And with this configurations I am not using MyReplyService anymore.

The above application context I have edited to add the gateway. I think I am messing up something. Kindly re advise.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use a JMS Outbound Gateway, which is intended for exactly this purpose?

Comment: It isn't clear how you are going to correlate reply, if you don't use `<int-jms:outbound-gateway>`... From other side with your current solution you never won't be able to deliver reply to the `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>`, because in your `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` there is no any info about `reply-channel` header. So, yes, reconsider your solution for the `<int-jms:outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: I am trying on what @GaryRussell and ArtemBilan has advised. Give me some time, I am a novice in SI.

Comment: @artemBilan and GaryRussell I have edited my application context, but I am still not able to achieve it. Something I am doing wrong, I am not getting it. Kindly have a look and advise.

Comment: any hint, highly appreciated.